# How to bind to selected item in an observable array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Using **knockout.js** I am wanting to update my **View** with the selected `Product`. My View's model is an `Item` that contains a list of `Product`s in a drop down list. When the `Product` is changed I want the view to reflect the selected `Product`s price and quantity.

I am passing the View's model, an Item, to my knockout ViewModel. An Item may not always have any products so how can I defensively code against this so I don't get any javascript errors with the selected product? On initial load the first product should be selected.

Lastly, if the Quantity is 0, I would like to display IN STOCK otherwise OUT OF STOCK.

Any suggestions/improvements on how to do this with **knockout.js** are appreciated.

Below is currently how far I've got with the code. I am having trouble showing the selected Product's quantity and price.

```
public class Item
{
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**View.cshtml**

```
<select data-bind="options: item.Products, value: selectedId,
                   optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Name',
                   event: { change: change }"></select>

Price: <span data-bind="text: product.Price"></span>
Quantity: <span data-bind="text: product.Quantity"></span>

var viewModel = new ItemViewModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

function ItemViewModel(model)
{
    var self = this;

    self.item = model;
    self.product = ko.observable(model.Products[0]);
    alert(model.Products[0].Quantity);
    self.selectedId = ko.observable();

    self.change = function ()
    {
        self.product = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.item.Products, function (product)
        {
            return product.Id === self.selectedId();
        });

        alert(product.Quantity);
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ94L/4/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `change` event binding. You bind to the selected product, and that is an observable, which updates the spans - this is the work that KO does for you.

```
<select data-bind="options: item.Products, value: selectedProduct, 
        optionsText: 'Name'>
</select>

Price: <span data-bind="text: selectedProduct().Price"></span>
Quantity: <span data-bind="text: selectedProduct().Quantity"></span>

var viewModel = new ItemViewModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

function ItemViewModel(model)
{
    var self = this;

    self.item = model;
    self.selectedProduct = ko.observable(model.Products[0]);
}
```

When the user picks a new product, KO automatically updates the selectedProduct object, which automatically updates the price and quantity bindings. Working JS Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ94L/6/).

Comment: Added JSFiddle at bottom of question.

Comment: OK I got it working, I will update my answer. I forgot some parenthesis, always an issue with KO !